# How can I install OpenSSH_7.6p1 on ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: software-installation, ssh, openssh

I want to install OpenSSH_7.6p1 on my Ubuntu 16.04.

This is the version that I have now:

```
$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
```

I want to install it so I could have the jump server version, with the J option:

```
ssh -J
```

I know that there is another to do that and I know how, but I want with `-J` option on Ubuntu 16.04, Is that possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try building this after you uninstall your current version.

```
wget "http://mirrors.evowise.com/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/openssh-7.4p1.tar.gz"
```

If you encounter errors, try

```
sudo apt install -y build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev
```

Then rebuild the source :-)

Hope that helps :-)